# Clearing a node value from and XML file with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML document

```
    <?mso-infoPathSolution name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:TCM-TCP:-myXSD-2012-02-20T14-33-22" solutionVersion="1.0.0.65" productVersion="14.0.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="https://devcoop.oceanspray.com/sites/TCM2/FormServerTemplates/TCM-TCP.xsn"?>
<?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?>
<my:myFields xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-20T14:33:22" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003">
  <my:Header>
    <my:ProjectName>Something</my:ProjectName>
    <my:ProjectCreationDate>2/21/2012 12:00 AM</my:ProjectCreationDate>
  </my:Header>
  <my:Details>
    <my:DescriptionOfProposal>
      Will be filled in when saved<html xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><p>testestdsgsgasfgf a<strong>asdf </strong>adf asdf asdf as</p></html>
    </my:DescriptionOfProposal>
    <my:PurposeOfChange>Will be filled in when saved</my:PurposeOfChange>
  </my:Details>
</my:myFields>
```

I want to run an XSLT file over this document that will clear out the value of the my:DescriptionOfPropsal node.  It will clear out the text and child nodes completely.  I have the following XSLT stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:my="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:TCM-TCP:-myXSD-2012-02-20T14-33-22"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//my:DescriptionOfProposal">
    <my:DescriptionOfProposal>
    </my:DescriptionOfProposal>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.  I have done a bunch of testing with it and I believe that it has something to do with the namespace on the node because I can do the same type of transform against another simple document with no namespaces and I can get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is obvious -- you are using incorrect namespace**.

The `my:DescriptionOfProposal` node in the provided XML document belongs to the namespace:

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-20T14:33:22"
```

However, in your XSLT code you associate the `"my:"` prefix with a different namespace:

```
"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:TCM-TCP:-myXSD-2012-02-20T14-33-22"
```

**Solution**:

Correct the namespace in your transformation.

**Replace**:

```
xmlns:my="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:TCM-TCP:-myXSD-2012-02-20T14-33-22"
```

**with**:

```
xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-20T14:33:22"
```

**With this change and a slight refactoring of the overriding template, your transformation becomes:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-20T14:33:22"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="my:DescriptionOfProposal/node()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when it is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<?mso-infoPathSolution name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:TCM-TCP:-myXSD-2012-02-20T14-33-22" solutionVersion="1.0.0.65" productVersion="14.0.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="https://devcoop.oceanspray.com/sites/TCM2/FormServerTemplates/TCM-TCP.xsn"?>
<?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?>
<my:myFields xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-20T14:33:22" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003">
    <my:Header>
        <my:ProjectName>Something</my:ProjectName>
        <my:ProjectCreationDate>2/21/2012 12:00 AM</my:ProjectCreationDate>
    </my:Header>
    <my:Details>
        <my:DescriptionOfProposal>       Will be filled in when saved
            <html xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <p>testestdsgsgasfgf a
                    <strong>asdf </strong>adf asdf asdf as
                </p>
            </html>
        </my:DescriptionOfProposal>
        <my:PurposeOfChange>Will be filled in when saved</my:PurposeOfChange>
    </my:Details>
</my:myFields>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<?mso-infoPathSolution name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:TCM-TCP:-myXSD-2012-02-20T14-33-22" solutionVersion="1.0.0.65" productVersion="14.0.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="https://devcoop.oceanspray.com/sites/TCM2/FormServerTemplates/TCM-TCP.xsn"?>
<?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?>
<my:myFields xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-20T14:33:22" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003">
    <my:Header>
        <my:ProjectName>Something</my:ProjectName>
        <my:ProjectCreationDate>2/21/2012 12:00 AM</my:ProjectCreationDate>
    </my:Header>
    <my:Details>
        <my:DescriptionOfProposal></my:DescriptionOfProposal>
        <my:PurposeOfChange>Will be filled in when saved</my:PurposeOfChange>
    </my:Details>
</my:myFields>
```

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else have diagnosed namespace issue and found a fix as well, please refer the answers to correct your code. However I would like to **suggest you something else than correcting those namespace**. Its usage of `contains() function` .. I know it is not useful here in this case but just to share knowledge I am writing that solution :)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()[contains(name(),'DescriptionOfProposal')]">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above code never cared about what namespace you are using in XML file :)

This is an alternative to that ..

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()[parent:: node()[contains(name(),'DescriptionOfProposal')]]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can use either of them :)
EDIT: the second method is least preferred because of reverse axes :)

 This method is added according to Dimitre's suggestion ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()[local-name() = 'DescriptionOfProposal']">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Generally good answer. There can be a few improvements. 1. `contains(name(),'DescriptionOfProposal')` is too general. It is more precise to use: `local-name() = 'DescriptionOfProposal'` 2. It is better whenever possible *not* to use reverse axes. So, I'd recommend writing `*[local-name()='DescriptionOfProposal']/node()` this is more understandable than `node()[parent:: node()[contains(name(),'DescriptionOfProposal')]]` 3. As you are not using any extension functions, line 3 and 4 can safely be omitted. Finally, I'd personally prefer the `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` on `xsl:output`.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace you bound to `my` is different in the XML and the XSLT:

XML:

```
xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-20T14:33:22"
```

XSLT:

```
xmlns:my="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:TCM-TCP:-myXSD-2012-02-20T14-33-22"
```

Either change the namespace in your XSLT or add a new one. E.g.:

```
xmlns:my2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-20T14:33:22"
```

And then in your template:

```
<xsl:template match="my2:DescriptionOfProposal">
    <my2:DescriptionOfProposal/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that the `//` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I change the XSLT so that the my namespace was the same as what is in the XML document and removed the // from the template match, but it still doesn't clear out the value